# Using the merge function in R for multiple values

Tags: r, merge

I have calculated multiple values of RMSE for my data, and would like to put it into one table using the merge function in R.
Here is the code that I currently have:

```r
merge(merge(merge(merge(merge(merge(merge(merge(merge(merge(merge(merge(RMSE_G_te, RMSE_GS_p, by = "name"), 
                                                                                RMSE_GS_sistar, by = "name"), 
                                                                          RMSE_GS_nistar, by = "name"), 
                                                                    RMSE_GS_s, by = "name"), 
                                                              RMSE_GS_t, by = "name"),
                                                        RMSE_GS_d, by = "name"), 
                                            RMSE_GI_p, by = "name"), 
                                      RMSE_GI_sistar, by = "name"), 
                                RMSE_GI_nistar, by = "name"), 
                          RMSE_GI_s, by = "name"), 
                    RMSE_GI_t, by = "name"), 
              RMSE_GI_d, by = "name")
```

The RMSE values were calculated using the rmse() function from the Metrics package.

Is there a way I can clean this up with a for loop?
Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Edit: I tried to put the values in a list and got the following error:

```
df <- as.list(RMSE_G_te, RMSE_GS_p, RMSE_GS_sistar, RMSE_GS_nistar, RMSE_GS_s, RMSE_GS_t, RMSE_GS_d, RMSE_GI_p, RMSE_GI_sistar, RMSE_GI_nistar, RMSE_GI_s, RMSE_GI_t, RMSE_GI_d)
reduce(df, merge, by = "name")
```

Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column

Comment: Don't use a for loop. Use Reduce(). I can't test without a reproducible example, but if you store all your dataframes in a list... Reduce(dfList, merge, by = "name")

Comment: @BillO'Brien Hi, the error I get is "unused argument (by = "scientific_name")"

Comment: Can you post the code verbatim that is generating the error? Did you put the dataframes into a list already?

Comment: @BillO'Brien Hello, you should be able to see the edits in the original post now. Thanks!

Comment: Reduce with a capital R

Comment: @BillO'Brien It still says "unused argument (by = "name") after the capitalization fix. Thank you.

Comment: Reduce(function(a, b) merge(a, b, by = 'x'), dfList)

Comment: @BillO'Brien what's the difference between a `for-loop` and `Reduce` apart from the syntactic sugar? The for loop might even be farster with the notion that it removes the overhead computations/ function calls.

Comment: @Onyambu, i think the major advantage of `Reduce` is readability/clarity. A for loop, with adequate indexing outside the loop, could be faster though, right?

Comment: @GuedesBF thats what I said. its just because of Syntatic sugar

Comment: @Onyambu Reduce isn't syntactic sugar; it's a higher order function. Merging a collection of data frames is a classic use case for reduce (as is cumulative sum, for example). I would rather use a "reduce" one-liner than have to use temporary variables, debug off-by-one errors, etc.

Comment: @BillO'Brien what is syntactic sugar?? MapReduce is a common syntactic sugar in many languages.

Comment: @Onyambu If you prefer to think of higher order functions as syntactic sugar, that's fine. You may even correctly point out that Reduce is implemented in imperative R for-loops. No argument here. I preferred to use Reduce here because it hides the complexity, tedium, and error-proneness of the imperative code alternative.

Comment: @BillO'Brien its not that *i prefer to think*. Its not subjective, but rather its objective. Yes, Reduce, is a high order function. But its use is for readability.  My point: One should not **discourage** the use of for-loops just to use Reduce, but rather should prefer the use of Reduce **because of readability**. your very first statement was **DONT USE FOR LOOPS** and that there is incorrect since by using Reduce you are still using for loops

Comment: When I call Reduce in R, I'm not *using* for loops any more than I'm *using* assembly language. All abstractions get implemented imperatively somewhere down the line, and I'm fine with that. The benefit of the abstraction is I don't need to care about the implementation details. This goes way beyond readability. That's all I have to say... feel free to get the last word in ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should first put all your data.frames in a list:

```
lst<-mget(ls(pattern='RMSE_G'))
```

then call base R `Reduce()` or `purrr:reduce()`:

```
library(purrr)
reduce(lst, ~merge(.x, .y, by='name'))
```

Comment: `ls` has a pattern argument within it. ie `ls(pattern = 'RMSE_G')`

Comment: Oh, you are right, i though about that but eventually did not include it. Updated the answer

Comment: had to upvote thisd. though no reprodu cible data was given, this seems to solve the issue